# Ability for a user to chose the amount of games they play - for loop

Tags: python

```
#Welcome Messages:
print 'Welcome To Rock Paper Scissors! '
print 'Game Settings:'
ammountofgames = int(input("How many games do you want to play?"))
#-------------------------------------------
#For Statement - Ammount Of Games
for i in range ammountofgames:
```

Basically, the for loop won't work but what I want it to do is allow the user to chose how many games they want to play which loops the scripts below however many times. Can someone please help me with this one, but most likely there is a much simpler way to do this.

Yes my spelling is really bad

Comment: Why not `for i in range(ammountofgames):` to fix the syntax?

Comment: for i in range(ammountofgames)

Answer (score 1):

the `range` function should be used like a regular function

Try

```
for i in range(ammountofgames):
```

This should work